# Keep SVG centred while using media queries

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, media-queries

I have a page where I've drawn several SVGs using d3.js. While building up the SVG graphics, I specified fixed heights & widths (which represent the max heights/widths that I wanted). This worked fine and with the CSS, everything was centred on the page, as I wanted. However, I also wanted the SVGs to scale when the screen width was below the fixed width.

To tackle the scaling issue, I removed the height and width attributes from the SVG and instead used `viewBox` (giving `0 0 <width> <height>`, and `preserveAspectRatio`. Cool - now everything scales to the full width of the page, i.e. like `width = 100%` in CSS.

So then I added my media queries. And they work - the max width of the SVGs is preserved, and below that they scale.
*But*: as soon as the MQs are active, the SVGs and their containing divs are aligned left. I've spent a long time fiddling with the CSS and also googling around and I didn't manage to solve it.

Here's my code (some things slightly simplified). Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<div class="overall-container">

<div class="svg-container">
  <h2>Smaller SVG</h2>
  <svg id="ebu-cb"
      version="1.1"
      baseProfile="full"
      viewBox="0 0 768 576"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  </svg>
</div>  

<div class="lg-svg-container">
  <h2>Larger SVG</h2>
  <svg id="smpte-cb-hd"
      version="1.1"
      baseProfile="full"
      viewBox="0 0 1280 720"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
      shape-rendering="crispEdges"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  </svg>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

Media query: *(works, but suddenly the `div`s with the SVGs are left aligned??? No difference if I add the media query inline of the SVG.)*

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  .svg-container {
    max-width: 768px;
  }
  .lg-svg-container {
    max-width: 1280px;
  }
```

I added all sorts of CSS options for central alignment, but I couldn't budge the placement :( I feel that I'm missing the obvious here (or maybe I should have a slightly different setup?) and I would really appreciate some help.

*Note*: the SVGs are generated in my JS file. I'm drawing them with the widths and heights specified in the `viewBox` attributes for each.

Comment: I can't see any corresponding elements in the markup with the class `.sd` and `.hd` mentioned in the media queries

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Sorry, fixed now. I simplified the code to make it more clear, but forgot to change the class names in the CSS. Thank you.

Comment: You have given a maximum width to the svg containers, do you want to maintain that max-width and get it centered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

The svg containers you have were never center aligned in the first place.

When the media queries were **inactive** ie. when you **did not** give a `max-width` to the containers, **they only looked like they were centered because they took 100% width** but as a matter of fact they were never centered.

You could notice that only when adding a `max-width` and reducing the width of the containers.

**Reason and Solution:**

You actually never gave it any property to center align. You need to give it now like so by adding `margin: auto` property:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  .svg-container {
    max-width: 768px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .lg-svg-container {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!   
I thought the `text-align: center;` applied to the body should be inherited - before I added the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes, the SVGs were indeed centre-aligned.   
But now I understand better why that did not continue after adding the SVG attributes.  
Your solution is perfect, thank you again!